# Как подключиться к MySQL в Docker извне через Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18?

Tags: mysql, docker

Хочу подключиться к базе извне, чтобы делать запросы.

На данный момент подключиться не получается, я не знаю куда копать дальше.

Изнутри подключаюсь вот так:

```
docker-compose exec mariadb sh -c 'exec mysql 
"$MYSQL_DATABASE" -u"$MYSQL_USER" -p"$MYSQL_PASSWORD"'
```

файл **docker-compose.yml**

```
mariadb:                                                                                            
image: mariadb:10.3                                                                                                  
container_name: seat-mariadb                                                     
restart: always                                                                       
ports:                                                                                                                                                                  
 - "1433:8000"                                                                                                                                                          
environment:                                                                                                                                           
  MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"                                                                                       
  MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}                                                                                                       
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}                                                                                                                                        
  MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}                                                                                                                                        
volumes:                                                                                                                                                                
  - "mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql"                                                                                                                                       
  - "./my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf"                                                                                                                                        
networks:                                                                                                                                                               
  - seat-network                                                                                                                                                        
logging:                                                                                                                                                                
  driver: "json-file"                                                                            options:        
    max-size: "10Mb"                                                                   
    max-file: "5"
```

файл **.env**

```
# Database details.
DB_DATABASE=seat
DB_USERNAME=seat
DB_PASSWORD=XXXXX
```